# Do I need to use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC if I set as default in DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wonder if I need to use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` each time when I set it as default `ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` ?

Here is my connection :

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$port = '3308';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;port=$port;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

And example query with fetch :

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users');
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

And `$user = $stmt->fetchAll();`

will them be enough without writing `$user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default fetch style of [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and [`fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) is `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` (which defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`).

You're setting `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` in your connection settings which overrides `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`.

So, basically you do not need to specify the fetch style in every single query. `$user = $stmt->fetch();` or `$user = $stmt->fetchAll();` should be enough in your case.